# How do we convert a (confusion matrix) decimal output to % with 2 decimal points when using the plot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, format

the matrix is plotted either with a % with many decimal places

or not as a % but with set decimal places

how can I do both at once

- a % with a set decimal place

```
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = cm) # Use ConfusionMatrixDisplay to visualize 'cm'
disp.plot(values_format='%')
```

Comment: try doing `%.2f`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
disp.plot(values_format='.2%')
```

[image]